# Generate different Custom IDs when multiple items are added at same time

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, caml-query, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list : Issues. I'am generating the IDs based upon the departments. There are 4 departments: FIN, IT, MFG, HR.

the ID format is

FIN001,FIN002.....

IT001,IT002...

MFG001,MFG002...and so on.

The logic I used here is getting the previous Issue ID based upon the Department and increment it(written in PreSaveAction).

It works fine if 1 item for a particular department is added at a time. The problem arises when multiple users add item pertaining to a particular Department at same time. In that case all the newly created items will get the same ID.

How can I generate unique IDs in this case? Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Are you using SharePoint Online or On-Prem? which version of SharePoint?

Comment: i am using sharepoint online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the "`Enforce unique values`" to `Yes` in the definition of your "`Issue ID`" column. That way the user that tries to enter the value that was already used would get the error to try to save the item again.